# DateTime multithread conversion not working

Tags: c#, .net

Basically my datetime conversions are outputting the same value even though the long passed to the convert function changes.

**EDIT** : the problem was only happening when i would invoke on the dispatcher thread.  Can anyone explain why?

I used this:

```
public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Dispatcher disp,
Action dotIt, DispatcherPriority priority)
{
    if (disp.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
    {
        disp.Invoke(priority, dotIt);
    }
    else
        dotIt();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by taking the datetime conversion out of the section of code that gets invoked on the dispatcher thread... but I still don't understand why it was happening.

Answer (score 2):

Because the ticks you've added aren't enough to change the seconds.

> A single tick represents one hundred
>   nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a
>   second. There are 10,000 ticks in a
>   millisecond.

Comment: He's not adding ticks with AddMilliseconds().

Comment: @Hans well thats debatable. Because milliseconds are a factor of ticks. So for example you have a length of 1 meter. You could either say I'm adding 2 cm or 20 mm, both are valid.

Comment: @Hans that's a mystery to me as well.

Comment: it does if you use a timestamp like 1299845374723000

Comment: @user404068 could you post your full code so we can run it and see the results.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp is already in milliseconds.  Don't divide by 1000.

How you got 3/11/2011 out of that code is rather a mystery.

Comment: the timestamp is microseconds.  by the time i print it out it is changed to milliseconds

Comment: Hmm, that's true.  I don't get the same second values that you do btw.  I get 34, 37 and 39.  I cannot explain how you got 09.

Comment: Maybe it is because the long timestamp passed to the function is taken from a dependency property..

Comment: You definitely don't want to assign it back divided by a 1000 then.  Use a local variable.

Comment: I tried using a local variable with the same result like this: long timestamp = timestamp2;

Comment: What sky did timestamp2 fall from?  Looking at this project through a comment box is too difficult, good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got your milliseconds conversion fixed, I wonder if it's the loss of precision converting long to double?

Comment: I don't think so but I'll give it a try.